# Spacing between tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I need to adjust the vertical spacing between three tables as defined in the following MWE.   `\vspace{30pt}` only works for between the second and third table. I'm suspecting this has something to do with the minipages defined but I need them for the footers beneath the tables.

Any clues?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\thempfootnote}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Z } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{YYYYY.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy} + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62.9\% (73.2\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{213} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + YYYYY.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{81.5\% (92.8\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{638} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80.9\% (93.8\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{560} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + YYYYY.\footnotemark[\value{mpfootnote}] + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{94.8\% (98.7\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{155} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results for a}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{30pt}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\thempfootnote}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Z } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{YYYYY.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy} + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{67.7\% (81.7\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{344} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + YYYYY.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80.4\% (92.6\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{810} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{82.1\% (94.2\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{727} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + YYYYY.\footnotemark[\value{mpfootnote}] + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90.6\% (97.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{267} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results for B}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{30pt}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\thempfootnote}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Z } \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{YYYYY.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy} + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{73.2\% (79.4\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{97} \\  
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + YYYYY.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{86.0\% (94.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{315} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.5\% (95.5\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{157} \\

  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{XXXX + YYYYY.\footnotemark[\value{mpfootnote}] + ZZZZZ.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90.5\% (95.9\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{74} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results for C}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always put a blank line in the source before `\vspace`, otherwise the space gets added after the current line, not at the point that you expect.